# Share HTML 5 player to facebook and issue with IPAD

Tags: ipad, html, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I have shared an mp4 video using Facebook graph API.It works fine on my browsers but it will play when i access facebook from my IPAD.

anybody know what is the issue?

This is my meta tags

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/testhtml6.php?id=8988">

    <meta property="og:description" content="test.">
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="600">

    <meta property="og:video:height" content="338">
        <meta property="video:release_date" content="2012-06-26 14:00:00">

    <meta property="video:tag" content="ass">

    <meta property="video:tag" content="ddddd">

    <meta property="video:duration" content="144">
 <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />

    <meta property="og:video" content="http://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/sample.mp4" />
<meta name="sailthru.image.thumb" content="http://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/fru.jpg">

    <meta name="sailthru.image.full" content="http://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/fru.jpg">

    <meta property="og:image" content="http://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/fru.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 100% clear what the problem is from the question. What does happen on the iPad instead?

One wild guess looking at the information we have would be to add a secure video url to the meta tags. If that is not provided and you are browsing Facebook over SSL, the video will not be displayed.

Add the following line to your `head`:

```
 <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://zoowork.com/binitha/flvshare/sample.mp4" />
```

Of course, the video actually has to be available under that url.

Answer (score 0):

1. the uri is wrong
2. the mp4 has to be encoded with baseline profile or it wont work on iOS:
   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html